# Rails 4 Ajax Get Request without view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Hopefully this question isn't too similar to others out there. I've spent a number of hours researching it, but apparently I don't quite know the terms to search for.

Using Rails 4, I'd like to use an ajax request to load data from a database table and use it to update a chart. I have succeeded in doing this by making a controller method and view, populating the view with the data, and then fetching that via ajax. **The question is: how can this be done without creating a view?** My solution is not terribly elegant, and I'm hoping for some more excellent solutions. I need to make a few more charts, and I would rather not make new views for each one if possible.

user_controller.rb

```
def asset_allocations
  @AAPL = ....
  @GOOG = ....
end
```

asset_allocations.html.erb

```
<div id="AAPL">
  <%= @AAPL %>
</div>
<div id="GOOG">
  <%= @GOOG %>
</div>
```

assets.js.erb

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "/allocations",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            var AAPL = $(html).find('#AAPL').html();
            var GOOG = $(html).find('#GOOG').html();
            show_pie_chart(parseFloat(AAPL), parseFloat(GOOG));
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
head :no_content
```

in last line of action
where view not need